DISNAKE | Как создать параметр в слеш команде с выбором канала(текстового)?
Хочу создать команду с подобным выбором как на картинке. У меня бот на disnake
код:
@bot.slash_command()
async def отправить(self, ctx, канал: , сообщение:str):
    await ctx.send("отправлено!")
    await канал.send(f"сообщение: {сообщение}")



канал: disnake.TextChannel

В аргументах команды указывается название аргумента и значение, которое он должен получить.
В данном случае ты можешь использовать disnake.TextChannel, в таком случае бот при вводе команды предложит выбрать один из каналов на сервере, в который нужно будет отправить новость.

Вы можете использовать disnake.TextChannel как вам и писали выше.
@bot.slash_command()
async def отправить(self, ctx, канал: disnake.TextChannel, сообщение:str):
    await ctx.send("отправлено!")
    await канал.send(f"сообщение: {сообщение}")

